# Downloading files from a website to parse

Tags: python, download

So I'm developing a python application that uses the data from

http://censtats.census.gov/cgi-bin/cbpnaic/cbpsect.pl

I've created a parser that parses the data I need from the .txt files that you can download from each data set at the bottom of the page. However, I'd like to make it dynamic so that it can work for any data set not just the ones I have downloaded. Is there anyway I can use python to grab the text files from the site? The files are downloaded as the same name so I'm really clueless as to how I could do this.

html code of the button :

```
    <form method=post action=/cgi-bin/cbpnaic/cbpsect.txt>
<input name=Year value=2013 type=hidden><input name=County value=017 type=hidden><input name=State value=38 type=hidden><input name=Noise value=YES type=hidden><input name=LFO value=YES type=hidden><input type=submit value="Save as text file.">
</form>
```

Comment: What you mean "depending on what the user chooses"?

Comment: Show us what you tried - you can't really expect us to write the program. The language of choice here is not Python, but R, which is geared towards statistics processing. There's a course about 'Getting and Cleaning data' running on Coursera at the moment.

Comment: @Andersson The user will input a location, and I grab that locations data.

Comment: @jcoppens Sorry, I'm not asking for spoonfeeding. I'm really just looking for some sort of example or a library that helps with this. I'm pretty restricted to what I can use due to time restrictions and my team. That's why I'm really looking for any insight if this is possible on python.

Comment: @BigBoy, It's difficult to understand the exact problem... The only question I found is "Is there anyway I can use python to grab the text files from the site?". The title is "Downloading files from a website to parse". Yes, you can simply automatically download text file from website using Python. Please make corrections to body/title if you actually mean another problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's possible. It'll take a little work though:

1. Look at [urllib3](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Furllib3.readthedocs.org%2F&ei=GeaCVe7yJsO2-QHCtYCoCQ&usg=AFQjCNFwZwBfqdMh5_IcI0iU03Y5Bny8FA&sig2=r6MyLvlqOgR2LKZEz4VBVg&bvm=bv.96041959,d.eXY) for downloading things from the internet. (Somewhat easier to use, but not in base Python, is the [requests library](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.python-requests.org%2F&ei=9-WCVdizGMGhgwSA_4AY&usg=AFQjCNFyAH9fsxdKUHgs_F_P-ZQ_-_P1nw&sig2=ehVL48a-h1UnpjOIM9KI_g&bvm=bv.96041959,d.eXY)).
2. As the files are requested with a POST http command, check the HTML source of the page you referenced to see which parameters you have to send in the POST command to get the page you want (hint, it's between a `<form>` and `</form>` tag. Eg, you need to add `state=19` to the POST query to get data for the state of Iowa.
3. In the download command at 1., you can specify the name of the file to save, which you could construct from the parameters of 2.

Comment: Thank you! downloading the library now. Just to make sure I am on the right track, I posted the html code of the button form. The parameters would be Year, County, State, Noise, LFO. That's the form you were referencing right?

Comment: Yep... In the form's attributes is the url you need to interrogate (says action=) and then you have append each of the parameters. The Requests site has a quick tutorial which shows show to do POSTs.

Comment: Awesome I got it! thank you. I actually used the urllib2 library and it worked well

Comment: Yes, urllib2 works fine. I've gotten a little addicted to Requests do-it-all automatically attitude... And, if the answer is helpful, please accept it (click the 'V' in the left column) and/or upvote it (click the triangle left). That makes it easier for others to see the answer.